# local storage-provisioner in rancher not creating the pvc

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, kubernetes-pvc, rancher-rke

We are trying to configure local-storage in Rancher and storage provisioner configured successfully.
But when I create pvc using local-storage sc its going in pending state with below error.

```
   Normal   ExternalProvisioning  4m31s (x62 over 19m)  persistentvolume-controller                                                                         waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "rancher.io/local-path" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal   Provisioning          3m47s (x7 over 19m)   rancher.io/local-path_local-path-provisioner-5f8f96cb66-8s9dj_f1bdad61-eb48-4a7a-918c-6827e75d6a27  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "local-path-storage/test-pod-pvc-local"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    3m47s (x7 over 19m)   rancher.io/local-path_local-path-provisioner-5f8f96cb66-8s9dj_f1bdad61-eb48-4a7a-918c-6827e75d6a27  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "local-path": configuration error, no node was specified
[root@n01-deployer local]#
```

sc configuration

```
[root@n01-deployer local]# kubectl edit  sc local-path
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"local-path"},"provisioner":"rancher.io/local-path","reclaimPolicy":"Delete","volumeBindingMode":"Immediate"}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-07T16:12:58Z"
  name: local-path
  resourceVersion: "1501275"
  uid: e8060018-e4a8-47f9-8dd4-c63f28eef3f2
provisioner: rancher.io/local-path
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

PVC configuration

```
[root@n01-deployer local]# cat pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: local-path-storage
  name: test-pod-pvc-local-1

spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-path
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

I have mounted the local volume in all the worker node still my pvc not getting created. Can some please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: @kkopczak thanks for update. We got the fix for this issue . PSP was not updated to use local-path hence not allowed attach pvc

Comment: for me, it was as simple as running "systemctl restart k3s".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your problem was updating PSP.

I would like to add something about PSP:

According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/podsecuritypolicy) and [this blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/06/podsecuritypolicy-deprecation-past-present-and-future/):

> As of Kubernetes  **version 1.21**, PodSecurityPolicy (beta) is deprecated. The Kubernetes project aims to shut the feature down in  **version 1.25**.

However I haven't found any information in Rancher's case (the documentation is up to date).

> Rancher ships with two default Pod Security Policies (PSPs): the `restricted` and `unrestricted` policies.

---

See also:

- [*The benefits of Pod Security Policy*](https://codilime.com/blog/the-benefits-of-pod-security-policy-a-use-case/)
- [*Secure Kubernetes cluster PSP*](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/secure-kubernetes-cluster-psp/)
- [*Pod Security Policies*](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/cluster-admin/pod-security-policies/)